# Trying to compile clang API project using g++

Tags: c++, g++, clang

I have just downloaded llvm and clang with svn, built it just like on the official site described and want to use the clang API. I have an example, which won't to be compiled=(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
 CXIndex index = clang_createIndex (
         false, // excludeDeclarationFromPCH
         true   // displayDiagnostics
 );
 CXTranslationUnit unit = clang_parseTranslationUnit (
         index,                           // CIdx
         "main.cpp",                      // source_filename
         argv + 1 ,                        // command_line_args
         argc - 1 ,                        // num_command_line_args
         0,                                // unsave_files
         0,                                // num_unsaved_files
         CXTranslationUnit_None           // options
 );
 if (unit != 0 )
         std::cout << "Translation unit successfully created" << std::endl;
 else
         std::cout << "Translation unit was not created" << std::endl;
 clang_disposeTranslationUnit(unit);
 clang_disposeIndex(index);
}
```

Command line looks like this:

```
g++ main.cpp -I/home/<user>/llvm/tools/clang/include 
-L/home/<user>/build/Debug+Asserts/lib/ -llibclang -o main
```

**UPDATE:**

The error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibclang
```

But libclang is in the /home//build/Debug+Asserts/lib/ directory.

Also tried using -llibclang.so except the llibclang - no matter=( ld says that it can not find the lib.

Anything helps, thank you!

Comment: What's the problem/question?

Comment: Indeed, what's the compile error you get?

Comment: oh, sorry=) It say's following: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibclang.so;

Comment: You shouldn't give the whole lib name, only clang, so -lclang instead of -llibclang if the file is called libclang.so

Comment: This works, thank you) But now another problem: when I start ./main, the shell says me: error while loading shared libraries: libclang.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; Should I add tle lib dir to my Path?

Comment: Thanks to everybody, everytinh works fine - had to add some libraries to the ld.conf